# Hreflang tag for Brazilian site

Tags: html, seo, google-search-console

I have a doubt about `hreflang` code for Brazilian website that works on BR and EN versions. I'm working on SEO services and I need to know know why this English version isn't recognized by Googlebot.
The website is: http://presscell.com and the question is about the  `hreflang`code:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt_BR" href="http://presscell.com.br" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en_US" href="http://presscell.com" />
```

According Google's Webmaster Tools, both versions are ok:

[Webmaster Tools's graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvOlZ.jpg)

So, what do I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO content not programming.

Answer (score 2):

Language code and region code need to be separated by dash, not underscore. So use en-US instead of en_US.